# Bind serverside function with Hyperlink control in asp.net web form page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have few controls on asp.net web form page and i want to link a code behind function to Hyperlink to resolve URL

HTML & Code Behind Example

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyplnkVideo" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# this.getVideoPageURL()%>'>
     <div id="dAlbumCategory" class="AlbumCategoryIcon">
         <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='~/Images/gallery/Videos.png' runat="server" />
     </div>
</asp:HyperLink>


protected String getVideoPageURL()
{
    string url;
    int PageID = Helper.GetPageIDbyName("Videos.aspx", Request["Language"]);
    url = "~/en/Videos.aspx?PageID=" + PageID + "&Language=" + Request["Language"];
    return url;
}
```

This Hyperlink control is not inside any grid view or repeater control. I tried several way but for some reason it doesn't call the function.

I would appreciate help in this regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in this way...

```
<% getVideoPageURL(); %>
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyplnkVideo" runat="server">
 <div id="dAlbumCategory" class="AlbumCategoryIcon">
     <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='~/Images/gallery/Videos.png' runat="server" />
 </div>
```

```
protected void getVideoPageURL()
{
string url;
int PageID = Helper.GetPageIDbyName("Videos.aspx", Request["Language"]);
url = "~/en/Videos.aspx?PageID=" + PageID + "&Language=" + Request["Language"];
hyplnkVideo.Attributes.Add("href", url);
}
```

This is running code.. so u can try it

Comment: I am not sure this is a way around or a nice trick. But it worked for me. I wish we had a direct way to call a method which would meet my requirement. Appreciate you replay. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
NavigateUrl="<%= getVideoPageURL() %>"
```

The appropriate tag would be <%=, not <%#, as the <%# and %> tags indicate that you want to run data binding code (as in, something you've returned from the database).

Comment: It doent work, It returns href with `href="&lt;%=%20getVideoPageURL()%20%&gt;"`

Comment: you cannot use inline asp.net syntax for any of server control's properties.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since this question was asked and marked as resolved.

However for the sake of providing a more appropriate resolution please call DataBind on your page code-behind in page load or render.This will inject the necessary href string.